# How do I choose where I want my Tkinter window to be located?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a weather app and the window always appears in random places on the screen, how can I choose where the window appears every time?

I tried using this: root.geometry('250x150+0+0') where the first two parameters are the width and height of the window. The last two parameters are x and y screen coordinates. I tried to find the exact coordinates of the center of the screen, but it was not working.

Comment: You tagged python 3.x and python 2.7. Please only use the version you're working with. Plus, 2.7 has long since been EOL

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this to center your Tkinter window.

```
w = 400 # width for the Tk root
h = 600 # height for the Tk root

# get screen width and height
ws = app.winfo_screenwidth() # width of the screen
hs = app.winfo_screenheight() # height of the screen

# calculate x and y coordinates for the Tk root window
x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
y = (hs/2) - (h/2)

# set the dimensions of the screen 
# and where it is placed
app.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
```